# react native TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.state.cartAmount')

Tags: react-native

In App.js if I assign **this.state.cartAmount** in **tabBarComponent** ... it gives error

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.state.cartAmount')
```

[image]

and if I set **tabBarComponent** to

```
{(this.state != null) ? this.state.cartAmount : '0.0'}
```

and Tap **TouchableOpacity** Home in **tabBarComponent** it gives error even if I write arrow function

```
HandleTabPressOne = () => {
    this.setState({ cartAmount: '12.20' });
}
```

I think there is some issue in constructor, please guide

[image]

```
const TabNavRoutes = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Tab1: {screen: HomeScreenStack},
    Tab2: {screen: Screen2},
    Tab3: {screen: Screen3},
    Tab4: {screen: Screen4}
   },
   {
    tabBarComponent:({navigation}) => (
      <View style={{flex: 0.1, backgroundColor: '#FF0000', borderColor: '#FF0000', borderWidth: 1}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 5}}>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.HandleTabPressOne.bind() } style={{alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 5}}>
                        <Text style={styles.textFAB}>Home</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tab2')}style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>

                        <Text style={styles.textFAB}>History</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.cartFAB}>
                        <MaterialIcons name="shopping-basket" size={24} color="#FFFFFF" style={{marginTop: 10}} />
                        <Text style={styles.totalCart}>{ this.state.cartAmount} €</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
   )});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Welcome: { screen: splashScreen },
  Dashboard: { screen: TabNavRoutes }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      cartAmount: '18.50'
    }
  }

  HandleTabPressOne() {

    this.setState({ cartAmount: '12.20' });
    alert(this.state.cartAmount)
  }

  render() {
      return <AppContainer/>
  }
}
```

Comment: seems state is not accessible in tabBarComponent ... ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
() => this.HandleTabPressOne.bind()
```

You have 2 binds here. You should do either arrow or bind. Try something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.HandleTabPressOne}
```

And your method can have the arrow bind

```
HandleTabPressOne = () => {
  this.setState({ cartAmount: '12.20' });
  alert(this.state.cartAmount)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(this.state != null && this.state !== undefined) ? this.state.cartAmount : '0.0'}
```